# Change HTML + Tab autocomplete (Sublime Text 2)

Tags: autocomplete, sublimetext2

When you type out the word like so
[image]

and then press tab it autocompletes to something like so...

[image: Autocompleted Image]

But I want it to look something more along the lines of this

[image]

Comment: Advance for Sublime3 is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35004161/how-to-make-sublime-text-3-default-templates. It works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one of Sublime's built in snippets.  You can edit the default one or create a new one.  To edit the existing,

- Preferences > Browse Packages
- Open HTML folder
- Edit html.sublime-template

The default snippet is below:

```
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[<html>
<head>
    <title>$1</title>
</head>
<body>
$0
</body>
</html>]]></content>
    <tabTrigger>html</tabTrigger>
    <scope>text.html</scope>
</snippet>
```

The content you want to edit is between `<![CDATA[` and `]]>`. The $0 and $1 variables are placeholders for content and once Sublime Text renders the snippet, you can move between the placeholders by pressing tab.