# How to make Sublime Text 3 default templates

Tags: html, templates, sublimetext3

In Sublime Text 3, when I create a new file (HTML, JavaScript, PHP, etc), is there a way to edit the default tags and their indentations? Currently, when I create a new file, say HTML, I get:

```
<html>
<head>
  <title></title>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

I would like to change it so that a new HTML file creates:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title></title>
  </head>

  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

Is this possible without plugins or will I have to search for/make one?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can change the default snippet with the [PackageResourceViewer](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) plugin.

- Install `PackageResourceViewer` through [Package Control](https://packagecontrol.io/installation)
- Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> and type `prv`
- Select `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource`
- Type `html` and select it.
- Select `html.sublime-snippet`

Comment: Thank you much! Worked like a charm.

Comment: These days there's an extra step between the last two steps - selecting the `/snippets` sub-menu item.